# localStorage not working as expected. Not saving when page is redirected

Tags: javascript

localStorage not saving variables when new page loads.

I've tried using variables, objects, and now localStorage to save data from one .js file to another. In javascript I use windows.location to change the page and all variable data is reset. All variables are global in scope.

// IN SEPERATE .JS FILE

```
var beganStory = false;
localStorage.setItem("beganStory", beganStory);
var isMale = false;
localStorage.setItem("isMale", isMale);
```

// IN ANOTHER .JS FILE

```
document.querySelector("#boy").addEventListener("click", ChangeToMale);
document.querySelector("#boy").addEventListener("click", Redirect);

document.querySelector("#girl").addEventListener("click", Redirect);

function Redirect()
{
    window.location = "StatsPicker.html";
}

function ChangeToMale()
{
    console.log("Changed To Male!");
    alert(localStorage.getItem("isMale"));
    localStorage.setItem("isMale", true);
    alert(localStorage.getItem("isMale"));
}
```

I expected the variable to be saved when the user clicks the element with id boy. The actual result is when the page is redirected the and I use the localStorage.getItem("isMale") it returns false.

Comment: When is the first bit of code run? Have you verified that it's running? And `ChangeToMale` isn't changing anything, it's just reading. Is that intentional?

Comment: Local Storage requires that the domains be 100% the same and the protocol be the same as well. So if you are redirecting the browser from say `http://example.com/` to `https://example.com` you don't have Local Storage anymore. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: You keep overwriting those values. The code that runs when the page loads needs to first try and read the values, and only set them if nothing is stored already.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever your page refreshes, not only are variables “reset,” in fact your entire set of JS scripts on that page are rerun. In your case this would include the portion that sets `isMale` to `false` in localStorage.